# change columns names of aggregation output

Tags: r

I use the below function to perform an aggregation operation which computes share by certain labels.

```
computeShare <- function(df, colX, colY) {
  aggregate(as.formula(paste0(colY, '~', colX)),
            df, function(x){length(x)/nrow(df)})
}

df_out <- computeShare(some_df, "colx", "coly")
```

This gives output `df_out` like below with

```
          colx          coly
1         name1 1.897315e-02
2         name2 2.988709e-04
3         name3 7.081621e-04
```

Instead of column name `coly` in `df_out` above, I want the name `Share`. I can do it via `colnames(df_out)[2] <- "Share"` inside the function like below.

```
computeShare <- function(df, colX, colY) {
      df_out <- aggregate(as.formula(paste0(colY, '~', colX)),
                df, function(x){length(x)/nrow(df)})
      colnames(df_out)[2] <- "Share"
      df_out

    }
```

Is this the right way to do this ?

Comment: You don't have to use the formula approach for `aggregate`. You can use the `list` approach instead, which would allow you to add names.

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 - can you elaborate on the list approach ?

Comment: As in `with(df, aggregate(list(share = coly), list(colx = colx), function(x) {length(x)/nrow(df)}))` or something like that...

Answer (score 1):

have you tried `setNames(aggregate(...), c("group","Share"))` ?